# Twitter Digit API Not work CURL php

Tags: php, curl, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-digits

I am working with twitter digit. my mobile verification works corrccetly. but with auth header information when I call curl then it not working.my curl code

```
$request=$_REQUEST['someData'];


function oauth_value($headersIndex = [])
{
    if(empty($headersIndex)) return 'Invalid Index Number';

    $value = explode('=', $headersIndex);
    return str_replace('"', '', $value[1] );
}

$headersData = explode(',',$request['headers']);

$ch = curl_init();


$ch = curl_init($request['apiUrl']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization' => 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="'.oauth_value($headersData[0]).'",
     oauth_nonce="'.oauth_value($headersData[1]).'",
      oauth_signature="'.oauth_value($headersData[2]).'",
       oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
       oauth_timestamp="'.oauth_value($headersData[4]).'", 
       oauth_token="'.oauth_value($headersData[5]).'",
       oauth_version="'.oauth_value($headersData[6]).'"'
  )
);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

example information that come form $_REQUEST['someData'];

```
Array
(
    [apiUrl] => https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json
    [headers] =>
     OAuth oauth_consumer_key="OybCXYoYTuS0Cw0usZYry6Nlj", 
    oauth_nonce="3942830480-TILitVHHZGmcczuuFj3nbJtnMm00DHvvgduawMHOybCXYoYTuS0Cw0usZYry6Nlj1445246231940",
     oauth_signature="dXHcH%2FsLBIlYOVWBIhEBWSCMLJo%3D",
      oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
     oauth_timestamp="1445246231", 
     oauth_token="3942830480-TILitVHHZGmcczuuFj3nbJtnMm00DHvvgduawMH",
      oauth_version="1.0"
)
```

What can I do Now?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a URL and header from digits then you can use below code:

```
$apiUrl = 'https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json';
$authHeader = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="**********", oauth_nonce="****", oauth_signature="****", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1481554529", oauth_token="*****", oauth_version="1.0"';

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Authorization: {$authHeader}"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($apiUrl, false, $context);

$final_output = array();
if($file)
{
    $final_output = json_decode($file,true);
}
print_r($final_output);
```

It will return id_str, phone number etc. You can store those data in your database.